# Multiple iptables.rules files or include statement

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I think that Title is self-explanatory. Anyway, what I'm looking for is a way to modularize my `/etc/iptables.rules` file, so I can easily manage them, e.g. a file with standard rules which all server should have and another file with custom rules that is managed in each server.

I couldn't find any documentation that points me in the right direction. I'd like to avoid dirty solutions, like using a custom script when loading rules.

To load all files in a dir (`/etc/iptables.d/*` maybe) in an ordered fashion (`00-*` before `10-*`, and so on) or to have an `include` statement supported by `iptables-restore` would be awesome, but again, I couldn't find any of these.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is a bit too broad to answer: You could of course do something like what you've described using Ansible's [`assemble` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assemble_module.html#assemble-module) module. Tools like [firewalld](https://firewalld.org/) attempt to provide this sort of modularization. Sometimes simply using [ipsets](https://ipset.netfilter.org/) can help you use the same set of rules on multiple servers.

Comment: I've found the same thing as you - I wish `iptables` or `iptables-restore` would support modular rules files, but they don't.  The alternatives are to create my own script/program to assemble a rules file from parts, or to keep the monolithic rules file under version control like a Git repository.